# How to use setAttachment with an ImageView

Tags: dominotogo

I'm trying to attach a photo to a Notes document using the setAttachment method. I have an ImageView on my attachPhoto.xml view that contains my photo:

`<ImageView id="AttachImageView" image=""/>`

The image property is set when a user takes or selects a photo.

In my attachPhoto.js file I have the following:

```
var doc = databaseName.createDocument();
doc.setAttachment($.AttachImageView.getImage(), "Attachment");
doc.save();
```

When I go to sync and upload the changes I get an error:

`"EXCEPTION: NotesDatabase.ynUploadFiles, Error: Invalid type passed to function".`

Any help on where I'm going wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

getImage() returns a File object, but for setAttachment() you need the path to the file as a string.
getImage().getNativePath() should work.

Comment: $.AttachImageView.getImage().getNativePath() returns null

Comment: where does the photo come in the first place?

Comment: thanks for the code, but I doesn't see the origin of the photo. Does it come from the camera? In the end you need a path the the file in the local file system, if you got this, the setAttachment() method should work.

Comment: The photo I am trying to attach is already on the device (iOS simulator). I've updated my code to show the entire selectPhoto function: https://gist.github.com/rbuening28/dc37dca8a7ab2171bf82

Comment: As far as I can see the photo is the iPhone's photo gallery and not in the local file system of the app? In that case you cannot get a filepath to the photo, I think you need to copy it to the local file system of the app first. I'm pretty sure there is a method to do that, but I don't know it from memory :-)